# Calling qmlRegisterType() in the registered class on debug crashes application

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to use `qmlRegiterType()` in registered class itself. I tried to use method from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37622694/call-qmlregistertype-in-the-registered-class-itself/37631455#37631455) but whenever I try to run application in debug mode it crashes the application with error

> read access violation at 0x0

Crashes on macro `QML_GETTYPENAMES` inside [`qqml.h`](https://github.com/Satius/qt5/blob/master/qtdeclarative/src/qml/qml/qqml.h#L235) (235 line).

`TestClass.h`:

```
class RegisterQmlTest : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit RegisterQmlTest(QObject *parent = 0);
};
```

`TestClass.cpp`:

```
QML_REGISTER(RegisterQmlTest);

RegisterQmlTest::RegisterQmlTest(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{ }

void RegisterQmlTest::foo()
{
    qDebug() << "Foo test";
}
```

I tried to compile application on MSVC2013x64 on Qt 5.6.2, on Windows.

Comment: You may be a victim of [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order). Don't use this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not the only one that it is happening to : https://github.com/benlau/quickflux/issues/7, and I believe it is likely due to the 
[static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

One solution could be to use [`Q_COREAPP_STARTUP_FUNCTION`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#Q_COREAPP_STARTUP_FUNCTION) to ensure the call to `qmlRegisterType` is not done too early.

You can use this macro in a .cpp file like so :

```
static void registerMyQmlTypes() {
    qmlRegisterType<MyType>("MyImortUri", 1, 0, "MyType");
}
Q_COREAPP_STARTUP_FUNCTION(registerMyQmlTypes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. The problem is that the [staticMetaObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#staticMetaObject-var) associated to your class is not initialized at the moment the macro invokes the call to [qmlRegisterType](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType).  As already stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37632059/3956540) (from the same topic), you're more flexible without macros. I solved this by introducing one static type per custom class.

#### appQmlRegister.hpp

```
#include <functional>

#include <QtQml>
#include <QList>

namespace app {
    namespace Qml {
        namespace Register {

            auto Init() -> void;

            static auto GetList()->QList<std::function<void(void)>>&;

            template <class T>
            struct Type {
                Type() {
                    auto initializer = []() {
                        qmlRegisterType<T>();
                    };

                    GetList().append(initializer);
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

#### appQmlRegister.cpp

```
#include "appQmlRegister.hpp"

namespace app {
    namespace Qml {
        namespace Register {

            auto Init() -> void {
                for (auto registerFunc : GetList()) {
                    registerFunc();
                }
            }

            auto GetList()->QList<std::function<void(void)>>& {
                static QList<std::function<void(void)>> List;
                return List;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The type `app::Qml::Register::Type` takes a template argument (the type of your custom class) and wraps the call to [`qmlRegisterType`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType) in a lambda. And that's the basic concept. Instead of an immediate call you now have full control of when to register all your custom types via `app::Qml::Register::Init()`. By calling that function at runtime but before starting the QML engine you can ensure that the [staticMetaObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#staticMetaObject-var)s are initialized properly and you're safe to register them.

This requires a bit of typing on a per-custom-class level though. You'd have to declare a static member in the header of the class you want to register in QML:

#### MyCustomClass.hpp

```
#include "appQmlRegister.hpp"

namespace app {

    class MyCustomClass : public QObject {
        Q_OBJECT
    private:
        static Qml::Register::Type<MyCustomClass> Register;
        // stuff...
    }
}
```

and then define it in the .cpp file like this:

#### MyCustomClass.cpp

```
#include "MyCustomClass.hpp"

namespace app {
    Qml::Register::Type<MyCustomClass> MyCustomClass::Register;
}
```

This can of course be extended to support other sorts of type registration like registering uncreatable types, custom versions/names etc. I implemented this in a QML showcase/template project on [GitHub](https://github.com/qCring/QMLApplicationTemplate)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this solution but It didn't solve my problem. Application still crashes on debug mode.